# Cross-platform "standard" way to accept file names with wildcards in C?

Tags: c, cross-platform, arguments, wildcard

I'm writing a command line utility in C to process image files.  In its current state, the application can accept multiple explicit file names though `argv`, but I'd like to add support for wildcards, like this:

```
imgprocess.exe *.png *.gif
```

or

```
./imgprocess *.png *.gif
```

It seems like this should be a common enough thing to be supported by C99, but I'm having a very difficult time finding a standard, cross-platform solution.

For Windows, it appears (via [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/expanding-wildcard-arguments?view=msvc-170)) that linking to `setargv.obj` does the trick, but that's specific to Windows and I think Visual Studio.

For Linux, it looks like [`readdir()`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Simple-Directory-Lister.html) or [`scandir()`](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Scanning-Directory-Content.html) can get me a directory listing and I can iterate through that to match files, but I think that's just Linux.

Since wildcards are such a common thing, I feel like I'm missing some kind of simple obvious solution.  Currently I'm on Linux compiling with gcc, but I would like it to compile for at least Windows and Linux.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 5):

On Linux-like systems at least, the shell expands the wildcard into a list of filenames.  So there is no need to add this functionality!

Answer (score 4):

The normal way to handle this problem in a UNIX or UNIX-like environment is to not handle it at all.  That is, let the shell do the glob expansion.  Your program just gets a big list of files and doesn't have to worry about looking around in the filesystem at all.  A quick example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And a couple of sample runs (the only files in the directory are `example` and `example.c`):

```
$ ./example 
$ ./example *
example
example.c
$ ./example *.c
example.c
```

Answer (score 1):

POSIX systems do support `glob` and `globfree` functions (try `man 3 glob`, becuase just `man glob` may get you the shell documentation) which do the same thing as the shell's glob behavior.

However--as others have said--it is not really common or expected that your program will process arguments that way: the user will have to quote the arguments to get them to you from the commend line.

---

If you want to be *really* cross-platform you may want to implement this functionality yourself. Say using PCRE (the Perl Compatible Regular Expression library) as the basis since this is available on all common platforms.